# Origen de "dar como a violín prestado"

Tags: expresiones, historia, colombia

Hay un colombianismo cargado de bastante ironía que dice

> **Dar como a violín prestado**: Maltratar algo.

Aparece en el Diccionario de Americanismos y a pesar de su uso cotidiano, su origen no me es claro (a nivel de época, pues se nota su fuente *sarcástica*) ¿Desde cuándo surge esta locución?

Comment: Intuitively, it seems to me to come from the idea that one might not treat something that doesn't belong to them as well as their own property.

Comment: Si te digo " a buenas horas, magas verdes",  o "me voy de picos pardos",  o "vete a hacer puñetas" hay un significado oculto, y te puedes remontar a un momento de la historia cuando había gente con mangas verdes, o con picos pardos,  o hacíendo puñetas,  para darle sentido a  la frase.  Pero no va a ser fácil buscar un origen si la frase se sigue captando a la primera, aunque nunca lo hayas escuchado, a lo más encontrar que ya al menos ya se usaba en tal o cual año.